# Can’t connect to a Sony SmartWatch 3 via USB in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

My Sony SmartWatch3 is shown in device manager (Windows 7, 64bit) as device without driver and the system can’t find driver for it.

Here are steps I have attempted to solve the problem that have not worked so far:

- Java updated to the last version.
- Installed Sony PC Companion application.
- Switched Avast antivirus off.
- Switched on Android Debug Bridge (ADB) debugging on the watch.

Any other ideas on how to connect to the watch or what can be done to install the driver?

Answer (score 2):

From [forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/smartwatch-3/help/version-t2970365#5):

- Power Off the SW3 normally Download and install PC Companion
- Click on "Support Zone", it will be downloaded
- Click on "Accessories software update" and then you can choose
  SmartWatch 3 and PC Companion App waiting for a SW3 connected in USB
- Start the SW3 by a long press on the power button until an image
  saying "connect USB"
- Connect the SW3, the driver will be automatically installed.
- Sony Companion App will detect that an update is available
- Download start and the SW3 is updated in less than 5mn

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Would you mind adding a link to the forum post where you got these directions from? It's a good idea to include links to sources in case someone wants to dig deeper. Thanks!